# RequestCanceledError when trying to connect

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

I'm currently migrating one of our services from the old NodeJS SDK version (2.6.12) to the most recent one (4.2.7).

For testing I run a local couchbase cluster using docker. The version is *Enterprise Edition 7.1.3 build 3479*.

When I try to connect to the cluster using our legacy code (and the old SDK version) it works. When I try to connect using the new SDK I get the following error:

```js
[RequestCanceledError: request canceled] {
  cause: [Error: request_canceled (2)] { code: 2 },
  context: undefined
}
```

This is the new code (bucket and username are the same), which throws the error in **cb.connect(...)**:

```js
const uri = "couchbase://localhost:8091"
const bucket = "test";
const pw = "password"

const timeoutOperation = 2;

async function run() {
    const cluster = await cb.connect(uri, {
        "username": bucket,
        "password": pw,
        "timeouts": {
            "kvTimeout": timeoutOperation * 1000
        }
    });
    const openBucket = cluster.bucket(bucket);
    const connection = openBucket.defaultCollection();
}

run();
```

This is our legacy code, which uses the old NodeJS SDK version. It works fine:

```js
async function connectToBucketOld(){
    const cluster = new cbOld.Cluster(uri);

    const connection: cbOld.Bucket = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let connection;
        const cb = err => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(connection));
        connection = cluster.openBucket(bucket, pw, cb);
    });

    connection.operationTimeout = 1000 * timeoutOperation;
    return { connection };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix the issue, but you don't need to specify port number if you're using a couchbase connection string. E.g. just use "const uri = "couchbase://localhost"

Comment: Please use SDK Doctor to diagnose connectivity issues :

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html

Also - a call to waitUntilReady() will show the reasons that the SDK cannot connect.

It's difficult to compare the old vs new  - the old does not show the hostname, username, password nor bucket name.

Comment: The new looks like it sets a timeout of 1 second (?)  on making the connection.  While the old does not.  The default timeout for making a connection is 10 seconds.  So the 'old' has much more time to create the connection before timeout and getting cancelled.